# convert date format javascript beforeshowday

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, format

```
    var dates = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewData["ph"]));
    //dates[0] = 16-09-2017
    //date = 09/16/2017
    $('#StartDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: JsDateFormat,
        autoclose: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                    console.log(date);
                    return [true, 'ui-state-highlight highlight-red', name[i]];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }
    });
```

how to change the date format from '09/16/2017' to '16-09-2017'? 
i had tried 
new Date('dd-M-yy', date).toString() - not working
date.toString('dd-M-yy') - not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function formattedDate(d = new Date) {
  let month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(d.getDate());
  const year = String(d.getFullYear());

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}
```

this function returns date in format you needed

Comment: this function return error "Expected {"

Comment: make sure you copied completely

Comment: 300% confirmed was copied completely

Comment: might be using older browser that doesn't support default parameter handling or string operation

Comment: @rahulmr  thank you for your reply ya

Comment: your issue fixed?

Comment: This relies on the built-in parser correctly parsing a non–standard date string. The original string can be reformatted without creating a Date.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using datepicker you can use [$.datepicker.formatDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

Here is a snippet using `formatDate` to compare the dates in the array:

```js
var dates = ['10-10-2017', '25-10-2017', '29-10-2017'];
$('#StartDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d/m/yy",
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (dates[i] == $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date)) {
          console.log(date);
          return [true, 'ui-state-highlight highlight-red', name[i]];
        }
      }
      return [true];
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"/>
```

Comment: the date was inside the function. 
function(date)...

Comment: as i know the date was in this format "09/16/2017", so how can i format the this date before it goes to my if statement?

Comment: I think you could use it like this `if (dates[i] == $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date))`

Comment: I edited the answer with a working snippet

Comment: thank you so so so so much for all of your replies~ it's work!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

ViewData["ph"] the date time will be converted to string with culture of the server in which the application is running so be sure to convert with this format in the server and assign to the **ViewData**.

If value passed to JsonConvert is a type of Date object then make use of the formating parameter to the method SerializeObject

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { 
             DateTimeFormat = "dd-M-yy" });
```

If you want to convert date to string refer the answer provide by @rahul mr
for all browsers

```
   function formattedDate(d) {
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}
```